# Session attributes coming as null in filter

Tags: java, xslt, servlets, session-variables, servlet-filters

Background: I need to create a filter which aims to capture the http response of a servlet whenever it is hit for the first time. Post that on subsequent servlet hit, I need to send the same http response back which i captured earlier. For this, i am saving the servlet response in a text file and send the same as part of response whenever servlet is accessed from second time.

Now, in my application, every screen is painted by 2 servlets. First servlet(for which i am saving http response) sends back basic template along with some dynamic xml data along with xsl name. During load of DHTML response of first servlet, 2nd servlet is called to fetch XSL. As part of security, during first servlet hit, xsl name is added as part of session attribute which is verified when second servlet is called to fetch xsl.

Now, The issue is when i capture http response of first servlet in the filter and re-send the same as part of subsequent hit, session attributes are coming as null in second servlet. (Ques 1: Why?)

Now, to think of the work around, i am adding the session attributes in a concurrenthashmap when I save the http response in the text file. And when the servlet is hit second time, i set the session attributes explicitly and send the response from text file. Now, again, during second servlet hit, these attributes are coming as null. To inspect more, i tried printing the concurrenthashmap in dofilter method. What i observed is that the value of the session attributes are getting null on subsequent servlet hit. (Ques 2: Why?)

```
public class ServletResponseMocker implements Filter {

    private ServletContext context;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> hmURI_FileNameMap=new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String,List<String>> hmURI_SessionAttrLMap=new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>>();

    private String rootPath;

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.context = fConfig.getServletContext();         
        rootPath=System.getProperty("WAR_ROOT_PATH");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    String uri = req.getRequestURI();
    boolean bToBeProcessed = false;

    if (uri.startsWith("some/pattern"))
        bToBeProcessed = true;

    if (bToBeProcessed) {

        res.setCharacterEncoding(System.getProperty("CHARSETTYPE"));
        OutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
        byte responseContent[] = null;
        String filename = null;
        if (hmURI_FileNameMap.containsKey(uri)) {
            filename = hmURI_FileNameMap.get(uri);

            responseContent = Utils.readBytesFromFile(rootPath + "\\somefolder\\"
                    + filename);
            res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            res.setContentLength(responseContent.length);
            HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
            if (session != null) {

                if (hmURI_SessionAttrLMap.get(uri) != null)
                    session.setAttribute("ClientXSL",
                            hmURI_SessionAttrLMap.get(uri));

            }

            res.setHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "SAMEORIGIN");
        } else {

            filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + ".vdb";
            hmURI_FileNameMap.put(uri, filename);

            ResponseWrapper wrapper = new ResponseWrapper(res);

            chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);
            HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
            // This session attribute is set by some filter in chain and is
            // always not null here.
            List<String> clientXSLList = (List) session
                    .getAttribute("ClientXSL");
            if (clientXSLList != null) {

                hmURI_SessionAttrLMap.put(uri, clientXSLList);
            }

            responseContent = wrapper.getData();
            /*Writing data to text file*/

        }
        out.write(responseContent);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } else {

        // To identify the 2nd servlet of the screen which is same for all
        // screens
        if(uri.startsWith("/someother/pattern/com.second.servlet.fetchXSL")){

        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            // Below session attributes always comes as not null during
            // fisrst time screen loading. However, comes as null when
            // static response is sent for subsequent servlet hit.
            List<String> clientXSLList = (List) session
                    .getAttribute("ClientXSL");
            if (clientXSLList != null)
                this.context.log("Getting clientXSL list from session:"
                        + Arrays.toString(clientXSLList.toArray()));
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

    public void destroy() {
    }


}
```

Comment: Please check for the `session id` (if any) in both the scenarios. If the session attributes are returning `null`, it could be a different session. I would suggest checking the value of `session id` of the `HttpSession`.

Comment: Yes i checked. It is coming as same. The weird part is session id does not change even if i open application in different tabs. Neither it changes if i log in / log out. However, session created time changes on login/logout and opening in different tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Found the issue.

For Ques 1: I overlooked the code present in second servlet. It clears the session attributes whenever it is hit. Therefore when i capture the http response of first servlet being hit second time, session attributes already got null. And hence, they were coming as null in second servlet.

For ques 2: Issue was with my code in filter.

```
List<String> clientXSLList = (List) session
                    .getAttribute("ClientXSL");
            if (clientXSLList != null) {

                hmURI_SessionAttrLMap.put(uri, clientXSLList);
            }
```

The session attributes were added in a list which was added as part of session. And then when i was copying the session attribute, i was not cloning it. Hence, the same getting cleared. To resolve this, now i am creating the clone and then adding it to my concurrenthashmap as below.

```
ArrayList<String> clientXSLList = (ArrayList<String>) session
                    .getAttribute("ClientXSL");
            if (clientXSLList != null) {

                hmURI_SessionAttrLMap.put(uri, clientXSLList.clone());
            }
```